# Learn CPLD from zero

Tags: verilog, vhdl, programmable-logic, intel-fpga, counter

a) Should I learn VHDL or Verilog? Is one excel in some area while the other better fit another area?

For simple "glue logic", says, 5 to 30 TTL chips equivalant, which is better?

b) First learning exercise is to implement a stop-watch counter. One I/O pin to start count. One pin to stop. One pin to clear. Same as MCU TIMER CAPTURE, but higher count frequency. Source of example program appreciated.

c) Second exercise is to PARALLEL LOAD counter into shift register. Send data to MCU, using software control CLOCK and DATA pins (or MCU hardware SPI), to reduce pin as in parallel out.  Example appreciated.

d) Altera WIZARD can create parameterized counter. Will WIZARD better than VHDL/Verilog in getting highest possible counting frequency to around 200MHz to 350MHz? Is FLOOR PLANNING easy to learn? Will Wizard/VHDL best suit FLOOR PLANNING?

e) I intent to buy Altera EPM570 development board. Is it suitable for above application?

f) Which brand/model consumer/industrial grade IC (CPLD or FPGA) has highest counting frequency (200 to 600MHz) for simple counter with START, STOP, CLEAR pins?

Comment: Although a potentially good question, this one needs a radical improvement, and therefore I've closed it. You should focus on one problem (no multiple questions) and make a clear question. Also it's not very constructive to ask for specific code, unless it's used to explain a concept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(a) My own preference is (strongly) for VHDL - in many ways, with VHDL, you know where you are, more accurately, than in Verilog. I described some of these ways in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant) and another answer there gave [this](http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel) useful link.

VHDL is said to be more verbose, but I find that its HLL features let me create hardware at a higher level, and that offsets the verbosity and makes my designs smaller and easier to understand.

That being said, if C is your favourite software language, you might well prefer Verilog, and either language will certainly handle your task. So it comes down to preference.

Either way, learn the simulator, and get into the habit of writing a self-checking testbench alongside your design units. Progress may initially seem a little slower, but definitely smoother.

(b) Example counter...

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

entity count is
    Port ( clk   : in  STD_LOGIC;
            -- reset : in  STD_LOGIC;
           start : in  STD_LOGIC;
           stop  : in  STD_LOGIC;
           clear : in  STD_LOGIC;
           data  : out UNSIGNED (7 downto 0));
end count;

architecture Behavioral of count is

type State_Type is (Idle, Run);

begin

Counter : process(Clk) is
variable Count : UNSIGNED (7 downto 0);
variable State : State_Type := Idle;
begin
   if rising_edge(Clk) then
       -- if reset = '1' then ... setup power-up state here
       if clear = '1' then
           Count := (others => '0');
       elsif State = Run then 
           Count := Count + 1;
       end if;
       if start = '1' then
           State := Run;    -- variable assignment
       elsif stop = '1' then
           State := Idle;
       end if;         
       data <= Count;   -- signal assignment
    end if;
end process Counter;

end Behavioral;
```

And a testbench. Note that it verifies the outputs and reports errors, rather than leaving you to stare at waveforms. That's what I meant by self-checking. To be even stricter I could set severity Failure and have it abort at the first error it finds!

```
  LIBRARY ieee;
  USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
  USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

  ENTITY test IS
  END test;

  ARCHITECTURE behavior OF test IS 
  signal testclk  : STD_LOGIC := '1';
  signal start    : STD_LOGIC := '0';
  signal stop     : STD_LOGIC := '0';
  signal clear    : STD_LOGIC := '0';
  signal test_out : UNSIGNED (7 downto 0);

  constant Tcy : time := 10 ns;

  BEGIN

  UUT : entity work.count
    Port map ( clk => testclk,
             start => start,
             stop  => stop,
             clear => clear,
             data  => test_out );

  --  Test Bench Statements

  testclk <= not testclk after Tcy/2 ;  -- 100MHz

     tb : PROCESS
     BEGIN
        wait for Tcy/2; 
        clear <= '1';
        stop  <= '1';
        wait for Tcy; 
        clear <= '0';
        stop  <= '0';         
        -- check counter is stopped and clear
        wait for Tcy;
        assert test_out = 0 report "Counter is not clear" severity error;
        wait for 5*Tcy;           
        assert test_out = 0 report "Counter is not stopped" severity error;
        start  <= '1';
        wait for Tcy; 
        start  <= '0';  
        -- check counter can count!  
        wait for 5 * Tcy;         
        assert test_out = 5 report "Counter is not counting correctly" severity error;
        report "Counter has counted to " 
                  & natural'image(to_integer(test_out)) severity note;
        wait for 5 * Tcy;   
        report "Tests complete : not a failure!" severity failure;
     END PROCESS tb;
  END;
```

(c) left as an exercise...

(d) For simple things like counters, my view is that vendor IP is just a good way to lock you into a vendor. Straight VHDL can be synthesised very efficiently and compiled for any vendor. When you get up to DDR2 memory controllers and CPUs, it's a different matter.

d2) Floorplanning may buy you 30% more speed if you are willing to take the time to learn it and fiddle with the placement of the design. My experience here is Xilinx; for Altera, YMMV.

e) How about a link to the board so we can comment?

f) Latest generation. If simple speed matters, choose the smallest (expensive) Virtex-6 over a large (cheap) Spartan-6 though I guess even the S6 can count at 300+ MHz. I can't comment on Altera products.

Comment: A lot of engineers use Verilog and there are many that prefer VHDL. You likely need to learn both if doing this for a living. However, I learnt VHDL from [this free book](http://www.freerangefactory.org/site/pmwiki.php/Main/Books) which I found very easy to read. VHDL fits which my obsessive nature a bit more! That website sells a little devboard with a paper version of the book for $79 which is nice (I haven't used this board though!)

Comment: Hi Brian, a) What is "habit of writing a self-checking testbench"? I guess you refer to, says, test vector for combination logic. How does it applies in context of testing counter, shift Reg, SPI? d2) Floor planning fiddling is all inside stimulator that can predict timing 'fairly' accurately without actual hardware, right?  e) Link for the board is http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=a1z10.1.1011-332653960.5.5F5JeV&id=5883976811. Very simple. All pins break out to  connector, a few LED, switch, buzzer and RS-232.

Comment: Also: http://www.fpga4fun.com/

Comment: If the data sheet states, says, 200MHz counting frequency, does it refer to BEST CASE performance from experienced designer capable of using FLOOR PLANNING and/or other advanced tools? For learner (likely stict to everything default), what may be the easily achievable speed PERCENTAGE from the data sheet speed?

Comment: (a) Testbench example now up. It's a separate program that exercises whatever you want in the design. The example doesn't test thoroughly enough! What happens at count 255 etc... (d2) Simulation is about basic correctness. AFTER that, synthesise then floorplan. Actual timings come from the FPGA layout tools, after floorplanning. That's an iterative process, but fast enough for a little design.

Comment: Don't rely on the datasheet numbers. I just ran the above counter, and synthesis estimates 544MHz in a Spartan-6 Which probably means over 500MHz after layout WITHOUT floorplanning. Don't get too excited, it's an 8-bit counter, a bigger one would be slower. (But that's what prescalers are for, right?)

Comment: Intended counter is 16 bits for enough resolution. Hopefully, 200 to 500MHz, using commonly/easily available consumer/industrial grade CPLD or FPGA. I am under impression that CPLD is cheaper and faster for this simple counter design, is that right?

Comment: 16 bits brings estimated speed down from 544 to 502 MHz. CPLD is likely to be cheaper and slower! than FPGA, I get the impression that CPLD tends to lag behind FPGA in process tech, but hopefully someone can give you actual numbers.

Comment: @carveone : that book is maybe OK for a complete beginner but subtly wrong in many minor points and badly wrong on some major ones. It'll get you going with some working but ugly VHDL, (what I think of as the "verilog subset") but doesn't even touch on writing cleaner VHDL (almost : it does mention integer subtypes but that's it!). Among free books, Peter Ashenden's "VHDL Cookbook" is probably still the best but tools have advanced a lot since it was written. fpga4fun deserves +1 though.

Comment: @Brian: I used wizard to generate a "framework" (since I not yet know who to create project from zero). Cut and paste your code to overwrite the Wizard generated code. Use everything default. Fmax for 8 bits is 142.59MHz and for 16 bits 124.47MHz on Altera EPM570T100C5N. Is Fmax close to REAL chip speed? Compare with your result, yours 16 bits is 92% speed of yours 8 bits. My 16 bits was only 87% of my 8 bits. Apparently, this chip is slower and drop faster from 8 to 16 bits.   I read CPLD faster than FPGA as being simpler. Not sure if enough to counter act improvement in process technology

Comment: Fmax is likely to be pretty close - you may get 30% or so by floorplanning in an FPGA but there won't be so much benefit to that in a CPLD. Re: slowdown 8 -> 16, one thing Xilinx do well is a fast carry chain, so your numbers look about right to me.

Comment: Beside floorplanning, any other tools to make Fmax faster? Does coding style affect Fmax much? I meant, software in C directly translate into ASM (excluding optimization) and directly affect speed. Is these "hardare description language" means that it is actually the 'compiler' making the real decision? That is, as long as the 'description' is not terriably bad (in text book sense), the compiler will 'FULLY understand' the description and give same hardware design/speed even when coding style differs?

Comment: Does coding style affect Fmax much? Heh. Move "if Start = 1 .. end if;" ahead of "if Clear ..." and find out! Make "State" a signal (declared on the line after State_Type) and try both ways round again. When you understand (from the other answer I linked to) why (and how) the order makes a difference with variables but not signals, you'll be in a better position to control the hardware you generate.

Comment: @Brian: Ouch! I was a complete beginner when I was reading that book. And that was only 2 months ago so I'm ill equipped to know better. Still, it gave me enough of a base to do what I needed to do. The 6GB of Xilinx Webpack is a painful first step though.

Comment: @Carvery : Yeah, a beginners book on finding your way round that system might be more useful! That book's not all bad - the biggest defects are the emphasis on tiny processes and 2-process state machines. They would have broken my little example up into 3 processes! Would it have been any clearer?

Comment: @Brain: Am I on the right thinking direction for text book searching? With physical TTL chips, we can see that a 'signal/state/condition' passing through how many logic gate/functional_block (like flip flop). Each step add propagation delay. How does STATE/VARIABLE/Order translate into different number of levels of actual hardware? STATE in your code will generate flip-flop, right? SIGNAL is a wire with hi/lo (and no memory), right? Order is whether the signal is at front or back side of a chain of combinational logic (like, multi level of AND gates), right?

Comment: Right general direction, but... signals can have memory too - make State a signal and you will see. But the number of gate stages does directly affect the speed. So, with State a variable, if you move the state change AHEAD of the count in my process, the count sees the NEW state - both steps occur in the same cycle, and the counter slows down. (Note this version is functionally different; as the testbench will show!) With State a signal, (see other answer re postponed assignment) there is no slowdown or change in function. This is a subtle point, but important...

Comment: Free : Peter Ashenden "VHDL Cookbook", or the one I've been dissing provided you treat it as a starting point. Non-free : Ashenden "Designer's Guide to VHDL". I've heard good things about Pong Chu (can't remember title) but I haven't read it myself.

Comment: Time to start book work. Any book recommendation for someone expereinced on TTL/MCU 'real' chip but zero on CPLD? Intended Altera EPM570T100C5N, Quartis II 12.1 web edition

Comment: First, since you emphasise speed, what speed do you get from that example in Altera's smallest cheapest new generation FPGA? before committing to CPLD...

Comment: Page 23 of data sheet, http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/cyclone-v/cv_51002.pdf, states Global clock and Regional clock 550 550 460 MHz for 3 device speed grades. Seem same range as Brain's figure on Xilinx Spartan-6. I only need something equivalent to 5 to 20 TTL. This is too big and $$$. It is 2 to 3 times faster so it will be a trade off away from desired speed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also a recent start-from-zero CPLD learner.  I chose the [Digilent Xilinx Coolrunner II dev board](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,1000&Prod=CR2-STARTER).

[image: 4 LEDs, 7-seg LEDs, 2 buttons, 2 switches]

The reasons I chose it were that Xilinx is a good brand, it was the first CPLD I heard of, the first one I read up on, the price was right, and the dev board is full-featured so I could start learning and not wiring.  I was also stunned that small Xilinx CPLDs were about $1 each. Of course, soldering these turns out to be more challenging ;-)

The dev board pictured includes a rather large CPLD, 256 macrocells.  This will be good because it will let you experiment without getting fitting errors.  If you intend to produce a product, you can get [64 macrocell breakout boards](http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/CoolRunner-II_CPLD_breakout_board) from [Dangerous Prototypes](http://dangerousprototypes.com/) for $15 each.  They include a button and an LED or two, so it could be a little dev board.  Most importantly, however, is that it includes a JTAG header so programming it is easy.

I have shoe-horned my project into 64 macrocells but have not yet loaded it into the DP board; I need more stuff before I can do that, so stay tuned.

The Xilinx products are supposed by the ISE development environment.  It's easy enough to use and basically 'compiles' the Verilog (or VHDL) into a binary that can be loaded into the (Xilinx) CPLD or FPGA of your choice.

I don't know the differences between the Xilinx and Altera products.  My project is small. If it were discreet old-school chips, it would include a 12 bit counter, a tiny EPROM, a few flip-flops, two 8-to-3 encoders, and a handful of AND and OR gates.  It was all I could do to make it fit into a 64 macrocell footprint.  In fact, I had to brute-force the fit using a compiler option. Thank goodness that feature exists!

I learned Verilog.  From my beginner's perspective, it was a good choice.  I am a programmer by trade, so I am unintimidated by Verilog or VHDL. It's all the same to me.  I am unaware that either is superior, only that they are different.

Judging by what little I have learned, the 200-600MHz you desire will be difficult to achieve.  According to the Xilinx ISE fitter/synthesis software, the maximum clockspeed on my design is 25 MHz.  I think it's pessimistic,  but that's still a pretty good clip. 100MHz is about the max for the CPLD I am using.